# how much can we rely on destructor?

Tags: c++

I came across this piece of code in our SW which relies on destructor to release a Lock. However when I ran the program, the destructor never got called and lock never got released.

```
bool someClass::someFunc()
{
    Locker lock(m_lock); //take lock in constructor, release lock in Locker destructor
    return something;
}
```

What's going wrong here? could compiler be optimizing this function to be inline ?

```
class Locker {
  public: 
      Locker(Lock& lock) : m_lock(lock) { m_lock.lock(); }
     ~Locker() { m_lock.unlock(); } 
  protected: 
    Lock& m_lock;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the destructor was never called? Can you give a complete, minimal repro?

Comment: Unless your program used a special system call to exit (i.e. `_exit()`), this is nearly impossible because [C++ is the king of RAII](http://lazarenko.me/2013/03/03/automatic-resource-management/). Please post a minimal working code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is basic RAII, destructor will be called..

Comment: I put breakpoints in gdb, prints in destructor, next call to lock gets blocked.

Comment: Please provide a complete, compileable source listing that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The destructor _is_ called.

Comment: "I put breakpoints in gdb, prints in destructor, next call to lock gets blocked." - then you know something else is locking it too... why not put a print in the `Locker` constructor and count the constructor/destructor calls? (May help to pass `Locker`'s constructor `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` or similar for logging). Also check nothing locks the same lock without using `Locker`.

Comment: The destructor itself will certainly be called. One thing to look out for, however, is potential copy or move operations performed on the `Locker` object, and the effects they may have. To understand this you'd need to look at copy/move/assignment functions of the `Locker` as well as the `Lock` class, too. Wrong code there can be the cause of a problem like yours as well. (This underlies once more that for this to be fit for an SO question, you'd need to provide a complete example, with _all relevant_ functions, so other people can reproduce the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the Locker actually releases the lock in the destructor? You can count on a destructor being called unless the program crashes or aborts or some other unusual circumstance occurs. Perhaps your debugger is showing the wrong values?

If the compiler optimizes it inline, the code will still be executed. "inline" doesn't mean the code is never ran.

Comment: class Locker
{
public:
    Locker(Lock& lock) : m_lock(lock) { m_lock.lock(); }
    ~Locker() { m_lock.unlock(); }
protected:
    Lock& m_lock;

Comment: What indications are you having that it's not being unlocked? Sometimes your debugger shows inaccurate information - can you output some text in the destructor to test if it's being called? C++ *should* call that destructor.

Comment: my only doubt was if inlining would prevent object going out of scope, I verified by small example even with inlining destructor is called. So more debugging in business logic !! Thanks All for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your observation that the destructor is not called is wrong. Here's how to prove it once and for all:

```
#include<iostream>

class Locker {
  public: 
      Locker(Lock& lock) : m_lock(lock) { m_lock.lock(); std::cout<<"locked\n"; }
     ~Locker() { m_lock.unlock(); std::cout<<"unlocked\n"; } 
  protected: 
    Lock& m_lock;
}
```

Ofcourse, this is just to satisfy yourself that the destructor is being called. Don't leave the lines in there :)